# Spring Crud on Nested Property

Tags: spring, crud, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring crud repository:

```
@Repository
public interface CrudCVVacancyMatchRepository extends CrudRepository<CVVacancyMatchEntity, Long> {
```

The `CVVacancyMatchEntity` object has an `Vacancy` property. I'm trying to write a query method on properties of the `Vacancy` property.

The following query method works fine (`Vacancy` has a string property called name):

```
Iterable<CVVacancyMatchEntity> findByVacancyName(String name);
```

But `Vacancy` also has properties as a set:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "vacancy_industries", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_vacancy", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "fk_industry", referencedColumnName = "id") })
private final Set<IndustryEntity> industries = Sets.newHashSet();
```

This doesn't work:

```
Iterable<CVVacancyMatchEntity> findByVacancyIndustries(Set<IndustryEntity> industryEntities);
```

I get `ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:146 - Syntax error in SQL statement`

```
select cvvacancym0_.id as id1_19_, cvvacancym0_.comment as comment2_19_, cvvacancym0_.cv_id as cv_id4_19_, cvvacancym0_.rating as rating3_19_, cvvacancym0_.user_id as user_id5_19_, cvvacancym0_.vacancy_id as vacancy_6_19_ from cv_vacancy_match cvvacancym0_ cross join vacancy vacancyent1_ cross join vacancy_industries industries2_, industry industryen3_ where cvvacancym0_.vacancy_id=vacancyent1_.id and vacancyent1_.id=industries2_.fk_vacancy and industries2_.fk_industry=industryen3_.id and .=? [42001-182]
```

Any idea?